# Retain good examples of succesful flags as a resource

Tags: discussion, flags

People often come on meta to question the usage of flags and try to get clarification on whether or not they made a good call. It's been discussed a lot, as the flags have some confusing wording, and also some people just misunderstand or can't agree on a read of them.

So why isn't there a retained set of questions that can be referenced as examples of accurate flag usage. The audits already draw on questions that are deleted, closed etc. Why not have someone choose a few of these autogenerated audits for each flag and then use them as examples for uncertain users?

I feel like this could have multiple uses.

- You can have a link to it from Triage and other review queues.
- You could link to it whenever a user fails an audit, show them when the flag they used *does* apply.
- When a user first gets the flag privilege, they could be linked to the saved posts to better understand the flags.

I know this is not a trivial effort to curate a set that demonstrates the system working correctly, but surely it will save effort in the long term?

Comment: I don't see any harm in adding Flagging as a section to the  [FAQ Index Community Wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) - there's a way to propose FAQs on that page as well if anyone wants to take it onboard...

Comment: Would there be a way to link deleted posts (eg spam) so that even new users with little rep could see them?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: no, but you can include example posts *in the FAQ post itself*. Just use quoting. Note that there is an endless variety of spam, however, as spammers try to evade detection.

Comment: I don't think it'd be sensible (not to mention impractical) to keep *actual* links to posts and flags - more a series of guidelines such as "When should I flag NAA", "When should I flag as Spam", etc ...(which I believe could be copied across from MSE)